# You do not have permission to view this directory or page Azure Dropbox

Tags: azure, deployment, dropbox

I am trying to deploy azure web app. Below is the link.

denemezk.azurewebsites.net

When I first create the page it works, it gives a default page that says you should deploy now.

But when I try to deploy something -anything- via Dropbox, it says "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" and even if i delete everything this never changes. It does not return to the default page, it still gives the same error message on the title. I can no longer use that page. How can I fix this?

Thank you,

I am editting this post because I dig a little deeper and find out that when I deploy things, I am deleting the hostingstart.html file.

What could I be doing wrong? and,

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have an index page in your Dropbox? `index.htm` or something similar? Are you clicking the Sync button under **Web App --> Deployment options** after making changes to your Dropbox folder?

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually go to the Azure Deployment Options and click Sync, this will pull the changes from the DropBox folder in to your wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 0):

The fist thing you should do is actually go and check the folders if your war got unpacked inside the webapps folder. for that if your web url is "denemezk.azurewebsites.net"  then try to open  denemezk.scm.azurewebsites.net. This  should redirect you to KUDU interface where you can see few tabs. From those tabs select Debug Console and then select CMD from the drop down. This should give you a folder structure.Now  Go to site->wwwroot->webapps . There check if your war got unpacked.
If not then try restarting the web app and see id this does the trick.
If while creating your app service plan you have selected the Standard pricing tier, change it to premium.
Last but not the list you can enable logging for you app. Then go to Monitoring-> Diagnostics logs . Turn those setting on. Then select Log streaming(Just below Diagnostics logs).
Hope this help.